# Why does Vagrant truncate hostname

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I'm setting the hostname in my `VagrantFile` like so:

```
config.vm.hostname = "demo.puppet"
```

However this ends up with a host name of just `demo`:

```
vagrant@demo:~$ hostname
demo
```

It seems that Vagrant will truncate at the first `.`, is this expected behaviour as plenty of examples on the web seem to have hostnames with `.` in them.

Comment: Try looking at the hostname with `hostname -f`

Comment: That does indeed return the FQDN `demo.puppet` but it seems that Vagrant/Puppet treats the hostname as `demo`.  I think the moral is not to use `.` in hostnames as anything after the `.` is part of the FQDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have anything to do with Vagrant. A hostname cannot contain anything but a-z, 0-9, and dash (-). When you set that hostname, you are setting your hostname as "demo" in the domain "puppet". You should use "demo-puppet" instead.

As a side note, I've started making a habit of including the hostname of the Vagrant host in my VM hostnames. It can come in handy later, for instance when deploying a build, you can include the hostname from which it was deployed. A line like this: `config.vm.hostname = "myapp-vagrant-#{`hostname`[0..-2]}"` in your Vagrantfile will do the trick, setting the hostname (in my case) to "myapp-vagrant-nhoover-osx".